# Show div based on if statement

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use this code to hide or show a div based on the url param "direction" I can't get this to work and wonder if there is a better way. Sample url = http://domain.com?direction=south&season=summer  - Thanks

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

        function getUrlVars()
        {
            var vars = [], hash;
            var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
            for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
            {
                hash = hashes[i].split('=');
                vars.push(hash[0]);
                vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
            }
            return vars;
        }

        var myVal = getUrlVars()["direction"];


        if(myVal == "north") {

            document.getElementById('north').style.display = 'block'; 
        }else {

            document.getElementById('south').style.display = 'none'; 

        }
        </script>
        </head>

        <body>

        <div id="north">Some text</div>

        <div id="south">Some text</div>

        </body>
```

Comment: You said "I can't get this to work." Can you be more specific? What unexpected thing happens?

Comment: Are you using JavaScript or jQuery? I don't see jQuery in your code.

Comment: Both divs appear all the time no matter what url param is present

Comment: @user1072100 this is because your javascript is running before the DIVs are present on the page ... you need to put your code in a function and call that function once the page is loaded - see my answer below ......

Answer (score 6):

You're missing a `$(document).ready` (if you're using jQuery) or `window.onload` block -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myVal = getUrlVars()["direction"];

    if(myVal == "north") {
        document.getElementById('north').style.display = 'block'; 
    }else {
        document.getElementById('south').style.display = 'none'; 
    }
});
```

or without jQuery -

```
window.onload = function() {
        var myVal = getUrlVars()["direction"];

        if(myVal == "north") {
            document.getElementById('north').style.display = 'block'; 
        }else {
            document.getElementById('south').style.display = 'none'; 
        }
}
```

It's possible that your code isn't working as the divs haven't been loaded in to the DOM when you're trying to show/hide them.

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/RTrgN/1/

Comment: +1 Hope you dont mind me adding a jsfiddle - was 3/4 the way there and found your answer ....

Comment: @ManseUK - don't mind at all, thanks for your jsfiddle generosity!

Comment: @ipr101 just noticed the OP changed the tag from jQuery to JavaScript and commented that they are not using jQuery ... i have added a basic javascript version ....

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in the if/else statement you need to show and hide the other div so that the correct one is shown and the correct one is hidden in each condition?

```
if(myVal == "north") {
    document.getElementById('north').style.display = 'block'; 
    document.getElementById('south').style.display = 'none'; 
}else {
    document.getElementById('north').style.display = 'none'; 
    document.getElementById('south').style.display = 'block'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a pure javascript method you need to add change the window.onload even to run your code - this ensures the DOM elements are present to run your code :

http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/RTrgN/2/

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = [],
        hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}

function runMe() {

    var myVal = getUrlVars()["direction"];


    if (myVal == "north") {

        document.getElementById('north').style.display = 'block';
    } else {

        document.getElementById('south').style.display = 'none';

    };
}

window.onload = runMe; // run the code once the DOM is loaded
```

Answer (score 0):

create a function, and assign it to the body's onload event. Also fix the styles from the if a bit.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

        function getUrlVars()
        {
            var vars = [], hash;
            var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
            for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
            {
                hash = hashes[i].split('=');
                vars.push(hash[0]);
                vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
            }
            return vars;
        }

        function myOnLoad()
        {
            var myVal = getUrlVars()["direction"];


            if(myVal == "north") {
                document.getElementById('north').style.display = 'block'; 
                document.getElementById('south').style.display = 'none';
            }else {
                document.getElementById('north').style.display = 'none'; 
                document.getElementById('south').style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
        </script>
        </head>

        <body onload="myOnLoad()">

        <div id="north">Some text</div>

        <div id="south">Some text</div>

    </body>
```