# If condition is true show button

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean

I'm trying to make a button appear if condition "isauthenticated" is "true".

used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317958/show-div-based-on-if-statement) as a reference, but not sure what's wrong with my code.

```
<button id="authentic" type="hidden">test</button>

<script>
    window.onload = function() { 
        var logedIn = ('{{isauthenticated}}')

        if(logedIn == "true") {
            document.getElementById('authentic').style.display = 'block'; 
        } else {
            document.getElementById('authentic').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What's `{{isauthenticated}}`? Set by the server? Ractive.js template variable?

Comment: check logedIn against _true_ and not _"true"_

Comment: Did you try to log to console logedIn value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok Guys, sorry for the bad question. This is what I was looking for

```
   <script>
   var isAuth = ('{{ user.isauthenticated}}');
   if (isAuth) true;

   document.getElementById("menuProfile").style.display="block";
   document.getElementById("showProfile").style.display="none";

   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if `logedIn` is a boolean value you need to remove the `"`'s from the `if(logedIn == "true") {` line

or just check:

`if(logedIn) {...`

Comment: ('{{isauthenticated}}')...we **suppose** it's a string but OP should check it first...

Comment: @Adriano: there is no suppose, it is definitely a string because it is wrapped in quotes. Unless `{{isauthenticated}}` also contains quotes, in which case the javascript will likely end up invalid

Comment: @musefan you're right. I suppose because I don't have idea of which server side processing is happening (maybe it's required to enclose {{variable}} inside ('')...)

Comment: @Adriano: Could be, OP really needs to be more specific if they want a good answer

Comment: @Adriano tks for the tips. Reason I am not more specific is I am starting to learn about JS. I am receiving this information as a String.

Comment: @Adrian Roworth I took the " 's out from it, but still doesn't work. tks though

Comment: have you console.log'd what `logedIn` is? to see what it returns in both cases?

Comment: @user2755801 **we don't know what you're doing server side** so we can't be sure of what that variable contains (and even not really sure about its type). Please provide more information or log variable to browser console to check what it is.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to Boolean Javascript documentatiion:

If the Boolean object has no initial value, or if the passed value is one of the following:

0,-0,null,"",false,undefined,NaN the object is set to false. For any other value it is set to true (even with the string "false")!

see what value does logedIn have before the if!